# Stanford Parser using command line

Tags: command-line, stanford-nlp

I am new to using the *Stanford Parser*. I would like to use the command line to receive the typed dependencies. I changed the directory in cmd to the file where the Stanford Parser- files are and then used the following command:

```
C:\...directory...\java -cp stanford-parser.jar edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexializedParser -outputFormat "typedDependencies" englishPCFG.ser.gz input.txt
```

`input.txt` is in the same Stanford-Parser file. But the I get the following exception:

> Loading parser from serialized file englishPCFG.ser.gz...
>   java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve "englishPCFG.ser.gz" as either class path, filename or URL

I tries some Syntax-modifications like brackets but it didn't work. Does anybody have an idea?

SOLVED:
java -cp C:\stanford-parser.jar; stanford-parser-3.2.0-models.jar edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -outputFormat "typedDependencies" edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz .txt